# How to achieve true material splating for large terrains?

Tags: shaders, eevee-render-engine

I'm running out of luck here so I need help.

My current project uses a LOT of images to textures a large terrain (7 groups currently that each is PBR so at least 4 maps. Meaning 28x 4k textures).
I'm quite new to the shader graph of blender, but I figured out how to use my splat maps (made in Houdini) and mask all the "materials" using Mix Shader nodes, I even tried the whole project with manual MixRGB nodes with the same issue.

The issue comes with Eevee : since it's a realtime engine, it is limited in how many textures it can use at the same time and the viewport quickly becomes unusable (GPU is 100%; VRAM is only at 20%).
Cycles still works (I'm not sure it has any limitation of this sort) but is becoming very slow (understandably).

Would you have any solution to keep using Eevee and my splatmaps ?

Modern realtime engines (like Unity) can blend materials together in a similar technique. Since it's separate materials, it doesn't overload the pipeline. Could anything similar be achieved in Blender ?